# How to configure timeout for user in django?

Tags: python-2.7, django-users, django-1.8

i use this line :

```
request.session.set_expiry(60)
```

to logout after one minute of inactivity but it logout after one minute from logging time

what can i use for this, 
and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only requests which cause the session to be altered are considered activity.

Use the `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` setting to alter the session every request if you don't mind the overhead. Other wise you can simply call it in every view ( with a decorator ) or add a middleware to do so.